# Whats the difference between hash generated and hash generated after mine

Tags: blockchain, hash

I am seeing this portal

https://anders.com/blockchain/block.html

When i type some data hash changes and when i click on mine button, hash changes again. I guess hash after mine is final one. Whats the logic for mine hash?

Answer (score 1):

The act of mining is generating a random nonce to try to get the hash below a certain number. So when you change data in the "Data" field, it just changes the hash to whatever the hash of the block number/nonce/data is. Then when you click "Mine", it's changing the nonce field until it finds one that comes with a hash below a certain number.

Comment: So you mean to say, the earlier hash was just a hash of block id and nounce and data. When i clicked on mine, it changed the nounce to solve the puzzle right?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, the form contains three editable fields: `Block`, `Nonce`, `Data`; and one non-editable field `Hash`.  `Hash` field always contains hash of the values of three editable fields combined together.  So, value of `Hash` field changes every time any of the values in editable fields change.

Button `Mine` try to find `Nonce` value that will make hash low, i.e. such a value that, combined with values in two other editable fields, will make hash to start with at least four hexadecimal zeros.  Once such `Nonce` value is found, is it placed into `Nonce` field.  As long as `Mine` button updates value of `Nonce` field, it triggers hash recalculation and thus value in `Hash` field changes as well.

Background color of the form tells whether current hash is low enough (green background) or not (red background).